# Component stylesheets effect other components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have login page specific stylesheets so I include them in login.component.ts,
and added all common css files in root index("index.html") with tradational way.
My issue is after user logged in system I expect to app.component ccs file go in action and take control of body but background color still remains as it was in login..

**When I refresh the page(page reload) its gone** but main purpose of using angular2 is being no need of refresh its single page app so how can I handle it..

here is my login.component.ts

```
import { Component,HostBinding,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth} from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
  '../../assets/css/colors/cyan.css',// this is the css file used only for login page
  '../../assets/css/login-page/form.css',
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
})
export class LoginComponent {

  @HostBinding('class') siteNavbarSmallClass = 'login-form login-form-second page-login-second';
  constructor(private auth:Auth){}
}


app.component.ts

import { Component,HostBinding, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth} from './auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
  'assets/css/global/slidePanel.min.css',
  'assets/css/colors/default.css',// this is the css file I want to use for others.
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') siteNavbarSmallClass = 'dashboard site-navbar-small';
  constructor(private auth:Auth){
  }
}
```

EDITED:
I think these screenshots make it more clear, css attributes for body element still exist after logged in this is why css properties coming by app.component hidden..

LOGIN page:

[image]

after logged in:

[image]

and after reload(what I expected):

[image]

so how can I prevent login component css properties effect other components(app.component, I am searching about "ViewEncapsulation" stuff but still think need help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated for your login and generally any component that you don't want it's css to bleed out.

And if you don't specify the encapsulation , the default is Emulated.